Looking for Mackey's PhD thesis, "The subspaces of the conjugate of an abstract linear space"
I'm looking for a copy of George Mackey's PhD thesis, The subspaces of the conjugate of an abstract linear space (Harvard Univ., 1942), but am currently struggling to find one online, with the only university library having a copy available being Harvard, which I don't have access to.
Does anyone here on MO have a copy, know someone who does, or is capable of borrowing it from Harvard and willing to scan it?

the only library that has it is at Harvard; you might want to contact them... https://search.worldcat.org/title/76991979?oclcNum=76991979

@CarloBeenakker Thanks, Carlo! I knew about only Harvard having a copy as a library, but it didn't occur to me to try to contact them. I've tried opening a request on their "HOLLIS Special Request" system (link).

Update: It turned out that the fee for getting a copy via the HOLLIS Special Request service is infeasible in my case (it's more than 20% of my monthly income), but it's nice to know that this is a thing that exists/is possible.

perhaps contacting someone from Harvard might be an alternative, they could borrow and scan the thesis?

@CarloBeenakker Do you happen to know someone who might be willing to do so? (I've also updated the question to note that this is a possibility)

we have some active MO users from Harvard ... perhaps one can be motivated for this service...

My friend Thomas Brazelton has offered to help -- you can reach him at brazelton [at] math.harvard.edu

@diracdeltafunk Thank you so much, Ben! I've sent Thomas an email.
